# Change bgcolor param value on mouse over?

Tags: css, flash, hover, mouseover, param

I have a .SWF email submit form. The background color is set via:

```
`<param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />`
```

and in the embed:

```
`<embed src="FILE.swf" flashvars="STUFF" quality="high" **bgcolor="#000000"** width="260" height="32" name="WidgetMailBlack" align="middle" swLiveConnect="true" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />`
```

Is it possible either on mouse over of the Object or a containing div to change those values? i.e. to #ffffff

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `wmode` parameter to `transparent`, get rid of the `bgcolor` parameter and use CSS to set a background color on the object instead. E.g.

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">

<embed src="FILE.swf" ... wmode="transparent">
```

And the CSS:

```
embed, object { background-color: black }
embed:hover, object:hover { background-color: white }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in the markup. You would have to call the movie again with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible, also it is possible to [change the containing div color](http://programming.top54u.com/Samples/Javascript/Javascript-DOM/Change-Div-Background-Color-Style/Default.aspx).

Flash has it's use, but Forms, unless in a proper RIA, would probably
be best left in HTML/JS. Here are a few handy resource to make pretty forms:

1. [Prettier Accessible Forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms/) - a bit old, but good
2. [Nice Forms](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/) - a really nice js library that makes styling forms easy.

HTH,
George